# Recommended Dump options for InnoDB dbs?

Tags: mysql

All my databases are innodb. The databases are small enough to not need binary log files and incremental updates. So i'd like to do simple backup dumps.

What options do you guys recommend for mysqldump when using only innodb databases>

I looked around and didnt find any advice i trust. It seems i can get away with `--all-databases --single-transaction`

Answer (score 2):

Have you heard of XtraBackup? It's an online tool for backing up InnoDB databases live, without locking any tables or interrupting service.

https://launchpad.net/percona-xtrabackup

It works remarkably well and has many many options. It's made by Percona, who are leaders in the MySQL consulting community.

It's probably worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no problems to "locking" all databases for the time take by backup to complete, I guess the `single-transaction` option is all you need to have a consistent backup.

Take care of this (from [Mysql manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_single-transaction)): A consistent read is not isolated from those (ALTER, CREATE, ETC..) statements.

Comment: to make use of it I suppose you should add `--skip-lock-tables` (because `--lock-tables` included in `--opt` and it's on by default)